# Can't connect to download packages

Tags: python, packages

I'm having problems getting packages (spicy, stats,etc)

I use python and need to install new packages but even when running on terminal I can't.

When trying to install homebrew I got the following error.

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

And when trying to get spicy I got the following.

```
$ conda install spicy
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
conda install spicy
Fetching package metadata: Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
.
Error: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: spicy

Did you mean one of these?

    spacy

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda spicy

$ anaconda search -t conda spicy
Using anaconda-server api site https://api.anaconda.org
Run 'anaconda show <USER/PACKAGE>' to get more details:
[ConnectionError] HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?type=conda&name=spicy (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x102f28c90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/bin/anaconda", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/scripts/cli.py", line 93, in main
    description=__doc__, version=version)
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/scripts/cli.py", line 75, in binstar_main
    return args.main(args)
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/commands/search.py", line 14, in search
    packages = binstar.search(args.name, package_type=args.package_type)
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/binstar_client/__init__.py", line 443, in search
    res = self.session.get(url, params={'name':query, 'type':package_type})
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Carol/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?type=conda&name=spicy (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x102f28c90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))



$ conda info
Current conda install:

             platform : osx-64
        conda version : 3.18.6
  conda-build version : 1.14.1
       python version : 2.7.10.final.0
     requests version : 2.8.1
     root environment : /Users/Carol/anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : /Users/Carol/anaconda
     envs directories : /Users/Carol/anaconda/envs
        package cache : /Users/Carol/anaconda/pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

Any ideas?

I'm using 
Mac Pro (late 2013) 
OS X El capitan 10.11.1

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 18:31:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
```

Comment: Does accessing the Internet work otherwise?  If you use a browser and navigate to `https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/`, what happens?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a DNS problem to me. The fact that you can browse the internet but is slower is possibly due to the fact you're not actually opening those pages but getting a cached copy from your local disk.

Additionally, the return code from `curl`, which is `6`, seems to confirm the DNS issue:

```
6      Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved.
```

Edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` file and put these 2 lines inside:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Those IPs are Google's DNS servers, which should work in most machines. Then, DNS resolving should work.